# c# Text adventure on windows forms?

Tags: c#

So iv been creating text adventures on the console but I want to move on to the windows form, but im stuck, I like using switch statements for the text adventure so one console I just need to put...

```
Console.readline();
```

but with windows forms it different, how do I make it so when I hit the button,it copies the text in the box(the smaller one) and then run a switch statement?
I tried searching everywhere but I cant find it, putting a switch in a loop just freezes the program, and just having the switch statement skips it. here is an example...

```
string choice;
choice = userInputBox.Text;

switch (choice)
{

case choice1:
{
 //event n stuff
}
case choice2:
{
 //event n stuff
}

}
```

but it runs the switch before the player cant type any input. What I want is for the program to wait until the player hits confirm to confirm there choice, then run the switch, and also have the button useable for different switch statements.

Comment: Windows Forms uses a more event driven system. Much like you'd do in javascript/jquery, you have to define a function that is run when a certain button is clicked. The application does not automatically wait for user input, like a console application does. In all honesty, I would suggest doing some tutorials on Windows Forms development, because it seems you are missing a lot of crucial information.

Comment: When you shift to a new UI technology you really need to do an introductory tutorial. Responding to user input is one of the first things any reasonable winforms tutorial will teach you - **it is highly googelable.**

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need to use Button control. Add a button control to your form with designer from toolbox. Then double click your button,and write your code inside the `button_Click` event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string choice;
        choice = userInputBox.Text;

        switch (choice)
        {

            case choice1:
                {
                    //event n stuff
                }
            case choice2:
                {
                    //event n stuff
                }

        }
    }
```

Also take a look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492173.aspx

Comment: I know how to add events, but that makes it so its one use, every time I hit that button it will only do that one event, im asking, how can I make this button a multi use button?

Comment: If he wants to enable the user to hit enter instead of clicking a button, he could use the TextBox's KeyPress event and check if e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return ...

Comment: @Hinek or he can set form's AcceptButton property

Comment: @Selman22 you're right, that's the better way ... long time since my last windows forms app ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look at event handlers. Assign the logic to the buttons onClick event.
Replace these handlers with alternatives.